# AngularJS repeat filter from input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem. I have this code but it does not work why? It works in an other project. I have a table and filter it with an input field.

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <br>
    <md-input-container>
        <label>search</label>
        <input ng-model="searchCManager" placeholder='lss_user_id'>
    </md-input-container>
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
        <tr class='header'>
            <td>user_id</td>
            <td>start_number</td>
            <td>lss_user_id</td>
            <td>agency_number</td>
            <td>business_unit_number</td>
            <td>office_id</td>
            <td>corporate_id</td>
            <td>asw_id</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in terminalOverview | filter:searchCManager " ng-class="{'noTerminal': x.terminals.length == '0' || x.terminals.length == 'terminal'}">
            <td>{{ x.user_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.start_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.lss_user_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.agency_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.business_unit_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.office_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.corporate_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.asw_id }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</md-content>
```

Comment: What is your error or misbehaviour exactly?

Comment: there is no error, when i type in the input all thinks are hidden. also when a valid/existing string is in the input box

Comment: Everything looks fine for me. Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: http://www.file-upload.net/download-12179820/dashboard.zip.html
sorry i cant create a fiddle now

Comment: Your link is not opening.

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/87oy/dashboard.zip?pt=kuR7pumidtuXbkJh7xo2dasopxpt%2Bq%2Bod4KRPrGgQiY%3D      goto slow download

Comment: Can't download. Provide fiddle.

Comment: https://github.com/zeus1999/dashboard2  its not a fiddle sorry i cant create one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter based on `user_id` Just try this

```
<input ng-model="searchCManager.user_id" placeholder='lss_user_id'>
```